# how can we add custom view (of gif image downloaded form url) below listview in relativelayout

Tags: android

I need to download a gif image from a url and give it to the custonview in xml.

Below the gif image listview need to be added . The problem is listview is not getting added below gif image in relative layout. Below is my layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Mainlay"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <com.android.gif.GIFView
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/GIFSingle">
</com.android.gif.GIFView>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
android:divider="#FFFFFF"
></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have to use Android RelativeLayout property

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_below="@+id/GIFSingle"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    android:divider="#FFFFFF"
                    ></ListView>
```

this property defines new view below previous one or take look at different properties for set to right, left, top, bottom.

Hope this solves your problem..

Comment: ya have tried this but once the image is downloaded i cant see the listview Only gif image is seen .If  the height of gifview is changed to 40dp then the listview is getting added below gif.i  want to use  only wrapcontent for the height

Comment: you can use scaleType property of Gifview this allows you to scale your image according to ur need,
or may be the case that listview was added but due to imag height it goes down and not visible on screen
so, put your RelativeLayout in i think name ..<Scrollview> tag..
reply if work..

Comment: tried using scaleType for GifView and have put the relativelayout in

Comment: scrollview i can just see the listview gif view is not seen

Comment: add your complete relativeLayout to <scrollview> and 
ScaleType is property which is used for normal imageview so you can use it inside this also, allows to scale image according to your need..

Comment: there is no link did you mean above question xml

Comment: public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
   throws IOException {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  
   initializeView();
  
 }
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  
   if (movie != null) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (moviestart == 0)
     moviestart = now;
    int relTime;
    relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
    movie.setTime(relTime);
    movie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    this.invalidate();
   } else if (bitmap != null) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
  
 }

Comment: post code by editing above question and this code where are the xml views, list and adding things to it can not getting you..